# matlab: how to select, filter, sort 2-d array like a table

Tags: matlab

I had

```
x1 = [0, 12, 0, 3, -1, 7] 
x2 = [1, -2, 1, 3, 12, 4]
```

Anybody knows easy way how to do something like "select x1 where x1>2 and x2<4 order by x1"?
so, I need:

```
x1 = [3, 12] 
x2 = [3, -2]
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to find the indices that satisfy your constraints

```
ii = x1 > 2 & x2 < 4;
```

Then you want to grab the values at those indices

```
y1 = x1(ii);
y2 = x2(ii);
```

Now you need to sort in descending order the values of y1 and save the sorting order to then sort y2. This requires using the second output argument of the `sort` function

```
[z1, jj] = sort(y1, 'descend');
z2 = y2(jj);
```

This gives me a different answer, but I would argue that `[3, 12]` is in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth pointing out the use of `sortrows` since that is intended for sorting 2D arrays, as was specifically requested in your question.  Here's how to do it selectively:

```
x1 = [0, 12, 0, 3, -1, 7];
x2 = [1, -2, 1, 3, 12, 4];
x = [x1' x2']
mask = x(:,1)>2 & x(:,2)<4;
sortrows(x(mask,:),1)'
```

The `,1` in sort rows say to use the first column, which is `x1` to sort the matrix.  Note the transpose operations when forming `x` and on the output of `sortrows`.